# Jetpack compose - trying to get sound to play in viewmodel fun

Tags: kotlin, android-mediaplayer, android-jetpack

I'm trying to play a sound outside of @Copmosable because of my application structure.

I have a validation routine which is in my viewmodel and based on the result I would like to trigger a sound but I cannot seem to get context working outside of @Composable

I get the following error in the MasterViewModel:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
create(Context!, Uri!) defined in android.media.MediaPlayer
create(Context!, Int) defined in android.media.MediaPlayer
```

Any pointers would be great thanks!!

```
package com.example.soundtest

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.soundtest.ui.theme.SoundTestTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SoundTestTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Greeting()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(mastVM: MasterViewModel = MasterViewModel()) {
    Text("Play a sound...")
    mastVM.playSound()
    
}
```

and the MasterViewModel

```
package com.example.soundtest

import android.media.MediaPlayer

class MasterViewModel {

    fun playSound() {
        val mp: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.correct)
    }
}
```

I have correct.mp3 save under res->raw-correct.mp3

[MasterViewModel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlcaF.png)

Answer (score 2):

I got it working!!!

I just include

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(mastVM: MasterViewModel = MasterViewModel()) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Text("Play a sound...")
    mastVM.playSound(context: context)
    
}
```

and then in the MasterViewModel like this

```
fun playSound(context: Context) {
        val mp: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.correct)
    }
```